# USB NAS not showing as a device in macOS. Systeminfo sees it as USB Device

Tags: usb, mount, nas

I'm trying to connect an old USB NAS with my Macbook Air 2020 (m1). It only has USB-C Ports, so I'm using an active Thunderbolt USB Switch with usb support connected in between. I connected the NAS to my raspberry pi earlier today and it does show up and is mountable.

My Macbook doesn't recognize it as a USB Storage device. It is neither listed in disk utility, nor in diskutil.

Sysinfo does recognize it as an USB Storage Device. It is in JBOD mode and has a 1TB and 4TB Drive in it. The ROG STRIX Arion is external USB Drive directly on the Macbook.

How can I mount this NAS?

[image]
[image]

Comment: that was it. i had another one of these "rare" usb 3 cables that are a bit higher than normal ones. Both drives mounted first time.

Comment: @SteveChambers if you add an answer i'm gonna mark this as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that it is the connection method (the switch) and/or the cabling.

The Mac can be a bit picky when it comes to cables/connectors (annoyingly enough...) so that would be what I would try first...